# Self-Adjoint in inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove if every projection operator is self adjoint.

Assume $P \in \ L (U)$ and  $P$ is a projection operator then $P^2$ = $P$ by the property of projection.

Then by the definition of self-adjoint, we have $\langle P u,u \rangle $= $\langle u, P^* u \rangle$
Then, $P^2 = P * P $ and hence $\langle P*P u,u \rangle $= $\langle u, P^* P^* u\rangle$ = $\langle u, (P^2)^* u \rangle$. Note that $P^2$ = $P$ since $P$ is a projection operator. Hence, we've proved that every projection operator is self-adjoint.

I am wondering if  I am correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one problem: You have used $\langle Pu, u \rangle = \langle u, P^{\ast} u \rangle$, which is not the definition of self-adjointness; in fact, the identity is true for every bounded linear operator $P$. Self-adjointness is defined by $P = P^{\ast}$, which implies that

$$ \langle Pu, v \rangle = \langle u, Pv \rangle$$

Thus your work, while all valid, does not prove that $P$ is self-adjoint. Furthermore, there is one important element that you're missing that will prevent you from completing the proof. It is in fact not true that every projection is self-adjoint. It is, however, true that any **orthogonal projection** is self-adjoint; that is, $P^2 = P$ **and** $(I - P)^{\ast}P = 0$. So you will need to add that as a hypothesis if you wish to produce the result.

Comment: I notice that **orthogonal projection** is self-adjoint. But even if I show that orthogonal projection is self-adjoint, How should show that every projection is self-adjoint? How do i link between orthogonal projection and generalized projection to prove that every projection is self-adjoint. Thanks for your input tho!

Comment: As I said, it is false that in general a projection is self-adjoint.

Comment: So, only **orthogonal projection** is self-adjoint. Thanks though!